# How to use next-auth with per page layouts in Next.js with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

The current code I have is below, which follows the tutorials for Next.js per page [getLayout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts) (see TypeScript section) and [NextAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668032/nextauth-type-error-property-session-does-not-exist-on-type) with TypeScript (or should I say, tries to follow...):

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { Session } from "next-auth";
import Header from "components/Header";
import { ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";
import { NextPage } from "next";

type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page: any) => page);

  return getLayout(
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I keep getting the error `Property 'session' does not exist on type '{}'.ts` on `pageProps.session`. What do I need to change the TypeScript to, to make this work?

Comment: Did you check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67464299/15814542

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a generics type to `AppPropsWithLayout`, then use it in the `MyApp`'s props type and pass the right type for `session`. Note that this will only work for Next.js 12.3 onwards, as support to type `pageProps` through `AppProps` was only added in https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/38867.

```js
import type { Session } from "next-auth";

// No changes to this type
type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
    getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

// Add generic type
type AppPropsWithLayout<P> = AppProps<P> & { 
    Component: NextPageWithLayout<P>; 
}; 

// Pass `{ session: Session; }` type as generic
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout<{ session: Session; }>) {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page: any) => page);

    return 
        <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
            {getLayout(
                <>
                    <Header />
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </>
             )}
        </SessionProvider>
    );
}
```

As an aside, I'd avoid wrapping `getLayout` around the session provider as it may cause issues with the context.

Comment: Comment on getLayout wrapping was very important; solved other issues I had!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to juliomalves' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032648/4019662) above, I did it this way

```
export type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
    getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
};

type AppPropsWithLayout<P> = AppProps<P> & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

const MyApp = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}: AppPropsWithLayout<{ session: Session | null; }>) => {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a couple days ago, I'll try to find the link but the solution was:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, }: AppProps<{ session: Session; }>) {

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
```

from one of the answers at: [(NextAuth) Type error: Property 'session' does not exist on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668032/nextauth-type-error-property-session-does-not-exist-on-type)

Comment: also just curious what tutorial are you following? what is `
type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};
`?

Comment: Made some edits to include the links. The solution you have here is just for NextAuth working with NextJS (same link I used!), but doesn't work with getLayout